# Add fadeIn and fadeOut effect to image lightbox JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox, fadein, fadeout

I have a jQuery lightbox where the user clicks on two links 'next' and 'previous' to navigate through images.

How do I fade in the new image?

Here is a snippet of my code of how the new image is replacing the old image.

```
var image = $(item).find('a').attr('href');

$('#lightbox img#image').attr('src', image);
```

Comment: This is what I use, it works really nicely and it's super simple. http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow . Of course you'll have to tweak it to change on click instead of in intervals.

Comment: yes that is a good slideshow but I have created my own gallery and just need that fadein effect. Probably the simplest part of the code I think.

Comment: Look how he handles the fading in that slideshow. It will work for you. He sets up separate divs and then manipulates their opacity and z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 proposed solutions:

**Soliton 1**

FadeOut (with opacity), change image, fade in again.

```
$('#lightbox img#image').animate({ opacity: 0}, 500, function(){
  $('#lightbox img#image').attr('src', image);
  $('#lightbox img#image').animate({ opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

**Soliton 2**

As mentioned by bricker, you can use a way as http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow  does, but to do so I think you can't avoid having two image objects at the same time. I suppose this would be more work for you in order to adopt your slideshow. But then you could fadein and fadeout at the same time.