# How do I add a fade effect to this slideshow?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fade

I have a slideshow here that I would love to give a fade effect.
Not sure how to do it, I am not very familiar with JavaScript, all I know is how to copy and paste a code ( even then I make mistakes)
The page is here:
http://lazlo.us/bw/getimages.html

I am using a PHP script to pull images from the directory to create the slideshow.

The JavaScript that creates the slideshow is very straightforward ( I found it on the the net):

```
var curimg = 0;
function rotateimages()
{
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "" + galleryarray[curimg]);
    curimg = (curimg<galleryarray.length - 1)? curimg + 1 : 0;
}

window.onload = function()
{
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 3500);
}
```

Anyone could help me to put the fade effect into it?

Lazlo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the src of the image, you'll need to insert a second element, and then fade that in.

Here's a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u94kcys5/) I threw together that uses CSS to handle transitions on `opacity`.

Basically, it will:

1. Create an image element
2. Insert before the existing image element
3. Wait 100ms, and then set opacity of the old image to 0

An image preloader would be helpful to properly kick off the animation as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you Jack. I am going to give it a try.

Comment: You could also try the solution suggested at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723727/add-fadein-and-fadeout-effect-to-image-lightbox-jquery/#7724796](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723727/add-fadein-and-fadeout-effect-to-image-lightbox-jquery/#7724796), which might be a bit simpler to implement

Comment: Thank you Jack and Brenzy for looking into this. Unfortunately none of the above solutions worked for me. Maybe it has got something to do with the fact that the images are pulled in from the directory via a PHP. script (getimages.php). Jack's solution would work if I specified the image names. I couldn't get Brenzy's solution to work at all,but that could be because of might have the wrong CSS syntax ( not sure).. Here are the links to the two different solutions you guys provided:  http://lazlo.us/bw/getimages3.html and  http://lazlo.us/bw/getimages4.html

Comment: Hi @Lazlo for getimages3.html, you will need to move the script to the bottom of your page (before the closing `<body>` tag). Right now there's an error being thrown because the script tries to query the element before it's available. You can also wrap the script in a `window.onload` handler, as well. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u94kcys5/1/

Comment: As for the recommendation by brenzy, you're facing a similar issue where the script tries to call an animation but the element isn't there. In addition, it'll only call it once. Here's an new fiddle with the jquery version (wrapped with jQuery's onload/ondomready shortcut handler): http://jsfiddle.net/1uav7dhm/ It's a different effect (because you're working with just one image - a fade out to white instead, rather than a transition/fade into the new image) - Also, I removed the CSS additions I made since jQuery uses JavaScript to animate the style property over time.

Comment: Jack, this one works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help !